# Can't understand gradle jar task code that creates executable fat-jar

Tags: jar, gradle, task

I am learning Gradle but I don't understand the jar task code that creates a jar with all the dependencies inside ( taken from Gradle Cookbook ):

```
jar {
    baseName = jarBaseName
    manifest { attributes "Main-Class": mainClass }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

My questions are:

1.The task name is jar. Because it's not written like jar<<{...} I'm assuming that this is run in the configuration phase, and not the execution one. Am I correct?

2.What exactly is configurations.compile? I'm assuming that some kind of dependencies classpath is queried, and each jar is zipTree-ed. Then all of this stuff is merged with the base classpath 
. Please elaborate about it

3.The zipTree method, I'm assuming it kind of unarchives each jar but I'm not sure. Am I correct?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes You're correct. When no action added (mostly with `<<` see docs) the code is run at configuration phase. The code You provided is also run at configuration phase.
2. `configurations.compile` refers to a configuration named `compile` using `configurations` object (a kind of a configurations container). Prior to gradle 2.0 `compile` configuration is provided by default with `java` plugin. AFAIR now it's called `javaCompile`. According to `zipTree` You're also correct.
3. Yes You're.

Comment: Thank for the confirmations :)